# What are command line arguments for sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I read somewhere that all arguments for sbt:

```
java -jar /home/robert/.conscript/sbt-launch.jar  arg1 arg2 ..
```

are the dependencies with which to start sbt.

**What about arguments starting with "@"?**

The question is because I want to discovery how [conscript](https://github.com/n8han/conscript#readme) is working.
It is just SBT with  '@/home/robert/.conscript/n8han/conscript/cs/launchconfig' as a first argument, other command line arguments are also passed to (through "$@" at the last argument for sbt).
The launchconfig is a simple ini like file:

```
[app]
  version: 0.3.4
  org: net.databinder
  name: conscript
  class: conscript.Conscript
[scala]
  version: 2.9.1
[repositories]
  local
  scala-tools-releases
  maven-central
[boot]
  directory: /home/robert/.conscript/boot
```

But there is no information about dependencies. Moreover conscript doesn't have any other file (besides sbt and cs runner, which is the sbt command).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page talks about Launcher configurations:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Sbt-Launcher.html

So you can basically configure sbt itself, e.g. add repositories where it should look by default, choose another ivy location, and so forth.